# Mapping one domain to another

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mapping

I'm failing to understand how I can map one domain to another without it looking like just redirected to a different domain.
For example, I have three domain names, abc.com, def.com and ghi.com

abc.com is the primary wordpress Web site, accessible via abc.com abc.com/postname etc. What I want to achieve is to be able to access any page by going to abc.com/page def.com/page or ghi.com/page all go to the same location and keep their url not redirected to the primary url.

I'm not even sure this is possible. I've managed to redirect pages but losing their url.

Comment: How did you setup the first domain? "I've managed to redirect pages but losing their url." - So the additional domains are resolving to the site? How did you "redirect pages"?

Comment: Easiest would be to have the DNS resolution of all three domains point to the same server and then use a fallback http virtual host to responds to all requests. No rewriting required for that at all.

Comment: An alternative would be to implement a transparent reverse proxy, the apache http server offers a proxy module for that. This keeps the URL visible in the browser's address bar unchanged, but it comes with a performance penalty, since ll requests need to get relayed (so result in a second, internal http requests).

Comment: Re MrWhite, what I meant was that if user went to def.com/contact, the url would be abc.com/contact, simple redirection of a Parked domain.

Arkascha, wouldn't doing is with DNS be the same as a parked domain?

Your second point about  the reverse proxy, I'd have to talk with the hosting company about that I suppose

Comment: "simple redirection of a Parked domain" - You use the term "Parked domain" - are you using cPanel? Or some other hosting control panel? Is this a shared server environment or is this your own server? You didn't answer my initial questions... "How did you setup the first domain?" - Because (depending on how you did that), setting up a second domain is really the same process.

Comment: I'm on SiteGround, which I assume is a shared server, i have many domains.  I'm not sure I understand what you mean by how did you set the first domain up, using the control panel,  I add a new domain to my account and then I can park domains under it or set up subdomains etc. Maybe I am not being so clear, I'm from a Microsoft background.

Comment: "I add a new domain to my account and then I can park domains under it" - This depends on the hosting control panel that you have with your account. If you are using cPanel then (providing your host permits it) you simply add a "domain Alias" (formerly called a "Parked domain"), once you've configured the DNS. If this is your own server and you are manually editing the server config then you add a second domain the same (similar) way you add  the primary/first domain - which is why I asked that in my first comment.